# Inject current language async-safe in all layers (ASP.NET Core 3 Mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization

I'm currently writing a localized website (ASP.NET Core 3 Mvc), and I managed to make it work and localize anything.

While refactoring, I noticed that language pollutes of all my project layers; I have to pass language from web to business layer and then to data, in all methods that need to retrieve localized data.

My solution have the following structure

- Common: cross cutting enums, extensions and constants
- Web: wiews, controllers, authentication (references BusinessLogic, Common)
- BusinessLogic: application logic (references BusinessLogic, Common)
- Data: data retrieval and manipulation (references BusinessLogic, Common)

Language right now is retrieved by

```
IWbHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("lang") as string
```

I didn't want to inject this dependency in all layers only to get language, but I made the problem worse.

*Is there a way where I can share current language between all layers, using a specific dependency, safe for use with async methods?*

**EDIT:** I don't want to use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture if there is not a way to inject it in constructors. Also could this be considered a safe way to get language in async environment?

**EDIT2:** my database is also localized, so language is a parameter in most queries.

This is how I configured localization

Startup.cs service

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(
        culture: "it"
        , uiCulture: "it"
        );
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>(){
        new CultureInfo("it"), new CultureInfo("en")};
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;    
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(
        0, new RouteCultureProvider(options.DefaultRequestCulture));
});
services.AddScoped<MainLocalizer>();
```

application

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern:
           "{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults:new{controller = "Account",action = "Login",lang = "it"}
       );
});
```

localization service

```
public class MainLocalizer : StringLocalizer<LocalizedStr>
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer _internalLocalizer;
        public MainLocalizer(
            IStringLocalizerFactory factory
            ) : base(factory)
        {
            _internalLocalizer = new StringLocalizer<LocalizedStr>(factory);
        }
        public override LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments]
        {
            get
            {
                return _internalLocalizer[name, arguments];
            }
        }
        public override LocalizedString this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                return _internalLocalizer[name];
            }
        }
    }
```

provider

```
public class RouteCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
    {
        private readonly CultureInfo defaultCulture;
        private readonly CultureInfo defaultUICulture;

        public RouteCultureProvider(RequestCulture requestCulture)
        {
            this.defaultCulture = requestCulture.Culture;
            this.defaultUICulture = requestCulture.UICulture;
        }

        public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            //Parsing language from url path, which looks like "/en/home/index"
            PathString url = httpContext.Request.Path;

            // Test any culture in route
            if (url.ToString().Length <= 1)
            {
                // Set default Culture and default UICulture
                return Task.FromResult(
                    new ProviderCultureResult(
                        this.defaultCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
                        , this.defaultUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
                    );
            }

            var parts = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/');
            var culture = parts[1];

            // Test if the culture is properly formatted
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(culture, @"^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})*$"))
            {
                // Set default Culture and default UICulture
                return Task.FromResult(
                    new ProviderCultureResult(
                        this.defaultCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
                        , this.defaultUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
                    );
            }

            // Set Culture and UICulture from route culture parameter
            return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(culture, culture));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you just set and read Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture ? Reading from the resource file would take care of everything automatically.

Comment: Shouldn't technically only the view part of the application be language dependent and the rest of the code should be language agnostic? What is the reason for your other layers to also handle language specific values?

Comment: that was my first choice, but i need to have an explicit dependency on the constructors

Comment: because i also need to pass language to database queries.

Comment: @albe depending on the version of .net you are using [it should be ok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_CurrentCulture)   "the app targets the .NET Framework 4.6 or a later version of the .NET Framework, its culture is determined by the culture of the calling thread"

Comment: yeah i was searching indepently and i think that async is not a problem. Asp core should not have thread problems [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: You shouldn't be using language in all layers. Language/Culture is all presentation. Anything else should be handled as standardized (ISO/UTC dates, etc.).

Comment: so if I have understood correctly, I have to retrieve from database the entire dataset in all languages and do the filtering by language only in web layers. Is it inefficient memory and bandwidth wise?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I am in the same boat as topic starter. Let's say I have DB where one of the entity is dependant on current user's UI language. User can switch the language in UI - entity needs to be reloaded (EntityFramework). Since this entity may be referenced by many others, it's convenient to use "one place" `HasQueryFilter` which contains currently selected language clause for the given entity. So what would you suggest instead?